# Sitecore: multilist during deployment

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How to enable the multilist to be control in content editor?
for example I have a list of item, item1 to item10. In the standard template value, I defined item1,2,3. After I have deploy the solution, how am I going to enable users in content editor mode or page editor mode to select item7,8,9 and 10?

And also, after I tested/rendered the multilist, only RAW VALUES are being rendered, is there any possible to render the item name such as item1? Do I need to customize the multilist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multilist control should be directly visible to the user in the Content Editor, you do not need to do anything else. Since you defined some items in standard values then those will be "pre-selected" when that item is first created. The user can then add the additional items as required.

To allow users to select values from the Page Editor you can [Use Sitecore EditFrame in PageEdit](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-sitecore-editframe-in-pageedit/)

The reason the item is being rendered as the raw value is because you need to get the item and then iterate over the target id's. There is [an example of this here here](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/06/ProgramaticallyItems.aspx)

```
//Get a multilist field from the current item
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["myMultilistField"];
if (multilistField != null)
{
  //Iterate over all the selected items by using the property TargetIDs
  foreach (ID id in multilistField.TargetIDs)
  {
    Item targetItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items[id];
    litItemTitle = targetItem.DisplayName;
    // Do something with the target items
    // ...
  }
}
```

You can use the following instead for the datasource of a repeater

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["myMultilistField"];
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] items = multilistField.GetItems();
```

Comment: Can I possible to do something like auto select those item if none of the item is preselected?

Comment: What do you mean, auto-select the standard values if no values are selected?